# Emit event with parameters in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

i'm trying to emit function with parameters like that.

```
template: `
    <div class="searchDropDown">
    <div class="dropdown is-active">
    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
      <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
        <span>{{selectedItem}}</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a class="dropdown-item" v-for="item in drop" @click="$emit('select-menu-item($event)')">
          {{item.name}}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  `
```

here is the i'm trying to pass item to method like a parameter.

here is my component which i try to emit function:

```
<search-component v-bind="searchProps" @select-menu-item="selectedITem($event)"></search-component>
```

and here is my method:

```
selectedITem(arg1) {
      console.log("cl")
      console.log(arg1)
    }
```

here is if i'm not trying to pass parameter everything well work so my method **selectedITem** is working. When i try to pass parameter like that nothing happened and i'm not getting some error.

Comment: FYI, as of version 2.2.0+, [`:key` will be mandatory](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component), so better include one.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle please?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/pejenov/edit?html,js,output @jom

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The following argument(s) in `$emit()` are the arguments in your emitted function.

```
$emit('select-menu-item', $event, 1, 2, 3, 4, "cupcakes")
```

and in your component method.

```
selectMenuItem: function(evt, num1, num2, num3, num4, food){

}
```

And in your actual component markup, you don't need to add arguments, just write the reference to the method **without parenthesis**.

```
<search-component v-bind="searchProps" @select-menu-item="selectMenuItem">
```

---

SAMPLE

```js
window.onload = function(){
 const component = function() {
    return {
       template: `
       <div>
         <button @click="$emit('click-me', 'foobar')">
            Click Me
         </button>
       </div>
       `,
       props: ["data"]
    }
 }

 new Vue({
       el: container,
       data: {},
       components: { "my-component": component(), },
       methods: {
          clickMe: function(str){
            console.log(str);
          }
       }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <my-component :data=$data @click-me="clickMe"></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this: <a class="dropdown-item" v-for="item in drop" @click="$emit('select-menu-item',  $event, item)">    then in component :  <search-component v-bind="searchProps" @select-menu-item="selectedITem($event, item)"></search-component>  and then in method :   selectedITem(evt, item) {
      console.log("cl")
      console.log(evt, item)
    }   and i'm getting : ReferenceError: item is not defined

Comment: no i'm getting the error on click  ReferenceError: item is not defined –

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. @Abana Clara's solution should work. And you seem to do it right too.

Comment: @user3348410 Found your problem. Edited

Comment: @AbanaClara i can pass string too but i cant pass the item which came from v-for can u look at fiddle https://jsbin.com/pejenov/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @AbanaClara i just  delete () from @select-menu-item="selectedITem()" and everything work well. Thank u so much! regards

Comment: ahh struggled quite some time wondering why wont work, it's better to highlight that the function should remove the parenthesis in order to work.

Comment: @titan sure, edited the answer to emphasize that the reference must not have a parenthesis

Comment: thanks for this one, I think this is the way to do it. :)

Comment: I dont understand. At first example you call $emit with $evetn object and in the last example you dont write $event object. What is wrong with me?

Comment: @Čamo You don't have to put the event object as an argument, it's completely up to you. The only thing that matters here is throwing the name of the click event [in the emit function] you referenced in your component's markup.

Answer (score 31):

just adding more answer from @Albana Clara.

You can merge your parameter along with the event passed.

EXAMPLE:

```html
<search-component v-bind="searchProps" @select-menu-item="selectMenuItem('test', ...arguments)">
```

```js
selectMenuItem: function(a, b) {
  console.log(a + " " + b);
  // test foobar
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful for when you want to pass in some extra arguments from the parent component.

Answer (score 12):

If anyone searching how **emits** work in **Vue3 with Composition API**:

In the child component:

```
<script setup>

  const emit = defineEmits(["updateItem", "updateCount"])

  function itemizedLot() {
    emit("updateItem", param1, param2)
  }

  function countedLot() {
    emit("updateCount", param3, param4)
  }

</script>

<template>
  <button @click="itemizedLot"> Btn1 </button>
  <button @click="countedLot"> Btn2 </button>
</template>
```

In the parent component:

```
<script setup>

  // access the emitted methods and their parameters

  function updateMenuItem(param1, param2) {
    ...
  }

  function updateMenuCount(param3, param4) {
    ...
  }

</script>

<template>
  <MyButton @update-item="updateMenuItem" @update-count="updateMenuCount"/>
</template>
```

Comment: This answer solution my problem thanks.