# How to add class to the parent component when the button is clicked in child in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, parent-child

I have a button in my child component and when I click this button I want to add a class in my parent component. I added child component as a slot in parent component.

parent component:

```html
<template>
  <div :class="editMode ? 'class-add' : ''">
    <slot name="default"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      editMode: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

child component:

```html
<button @click="addClass">Click Me!!!</button>

addClass() {
  this.$emit('edit-abc', true);
},
```

And here how I am adding the class:

```html
<parent-component :edit-mode="editMode">
  <template #default>
    <child-component @edit-abc="editAbc($event)" />
  </template>
</parent-component>
```

The problem is as you see, I have several abcs (abcs is an object which includes several abc) to send to child the class only the one which is clicked. So I believe here `@edit-abc="editMode = $event"`, instead of `editMode = $event`, I need to create a function and filter the one that I want to add the class but my logic is wrong somewhere. Here what I have done as a function.

```js
editAbc(event) {
  this.abcs.filter((a) => {
    if (a.id) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        return (this.editMode = event);
      });
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emit event with parameters in vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738919/emit-event-with-parameters-in-vue)

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the `editMode` data property to use it in your event handling.

```
 data() {
    return {
      editMode: false
    };
  }
```

If you need to send separate events, then simply use **different** events.

You intentions with *"several abcs"* are not really clear. And it looks for me like you have a design flaw.

Please clarify it further.

**UPDATE**

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-pojfkj?file=src/App.vue) with the solution.

Comment: abcs is an object which includes several abc. each abc has an id and name. Am I more clear? Please let me know and I can make it clear

Comment: Check the stackblitz sandbox

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your answer clarifies the function but it doesnt change the selected abc's click event from abcs object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your answer clarifies the function but it doesnt change the selected abc's click event from abcs object.

Comment: You can send in the event anything you want. Like this `this.$emit('edit-abc', this.abc);` or whatever you need.